# Difficulty formatting insert into Joomla SQL call in PHP script

Tags: php, sql, joomla, insert-into

Here is the PHP snippet:

```
$rdcno = rawurlencode('[cb_rdcno]');
$web_id = 'TEST';

$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$emailListQuery = $db->getQuery(true);

$emailListQuery = "INSERT INTO `#__update_membership` (`inl_rdcnumber`, `inl_website_id`) VALUES ('$rdcno', '$web_id')";
$db->setQuery( $emailListQuery );
$db->query();
```

Where did I go wrong with the formatting of the query?

Answer (score 1):

You should actually stick to Joomla coding standards, ensuring that you also use escaping methods as shown below:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$emailListQuery = $db->getQuery(true);

$columns = array('inl_rdcnumber', 'inl_website_id');
$values = array($db->quote($rdcno), $db->quote($web_id));

$emailListQuery->insert($db->quoteName('#__update_membership'))
               ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
               ->values(implode(',', $values));

$db->setQuery($emailListQuery);
$db->query();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: query() is deprcated, so you should use execute() instead.

Comment: @Elin - Indeed but only for 3.0+, not 2.5. Wasn't sure what the OP was using so stuck with query()